# Why does Internet Explorer repeatedly prompt to reinstall Silverlight?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, reinstall, silverlight

Internet Explorer 11 repeatedly tells me I need to install Silverlight.  However, I have already installed (and uninstalled and reinstalled) Silverlight several times with no success.  I have even tried uninstalling with an advanced tool ([Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)).  I am using Internet Explorer 11 x64 on Windows 7.

Silverlight works fine on the same system in Chrome and Firefox--just not in IE 11.  I am a software developer, and so I have Silverlight SDKs, though it seems to me that should make no difference.

So why does Internet Explorer not recognize the Silverlight installation?

Comment: One possible problem is the fact your using IEx64.  Does this problem happen if you use IEx86 which chrome and Firefox both are.

Comment: @Ramhound--I had tried opening IE 32-bit version, too, but had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable the Silverlight add-on in IE (thanks to a post [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ie8-silverlight-silverlight-repeatedly-prompts-to/a1bc911f-fe22-4095-a5a4-7adb71b47d0f)):

1. Click "tool" icon in upper-left of IE
2. Manage add-ons
3. Show "All add-ons" (left pane)
4. "Microsoft Corporation" category
5. Select "Microsoft Silverlight"
6. Click "Enable"

Comment: Sometimes this could be due to Activex Filtering is on.. you need to turn off Activex Filtering.  Silverlight  is an ActiveX control and when filtering is enabled Silverlight content will not be displayed on a webpage. Instead it will display silverlight install request ! http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2016/10/solved-internet-explorer-cant-detect-silverlight-silverlight-already-installed.html